# Android tab issue

Tags: android, tabs

I am using  tabs in my application but It getting crash.please help me.
here is my tab code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_tab);
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        //tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG)
                .setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home_selector))
                .setContent(new Intent(this, TabGroupHomeActivity.class)));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post stacktrace from Logcat

Comment: "It getting crash" -> which one ?

Comment: post the code of your TabGroupHomeActivity please

Comment: not get any answers yer ;)

Comment: I reslove it by my self...

Comment: hmm great .... god work